# MVC Web Application basic design

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a small web application project that I would like to develop using the Microsoft MVC4 framework. I have very little experience with web development so please bear with me.

For the most part it is a typical data, business logic, view web application. However, there are also a few operations that are CPU intensive and take considerable time to return a result (they are requested directly by the user with parameters).

I have considered writing a separate web service that would only be responsible for the expensive operations so as to reduce the load on the main web application but I am not sure if that is correct. Also, if I do use a separate web service, what component of the web application should be talking to it? The view, through an AJAX call, the controller..?

Can I have some quick guidelines about how to put all of this together?

Comment: Does the user need to wait for the result of the long running process?

Comment: I was thinking of implementing it as follows: the user makes the request. They then poll the service at regular intervals until the result is available. (I am also not sure if this is a good strategy)

Answer (score 0):

> what component of the web application should be talking to it?

The controller. The view should only call your controller actions. Then it is the responsibility of the controller to query some services, build a model and pass this model to a view.

Comment: OK so then I have the following situation: the way I implemented the long request is via a ticket. I.e.: I make the request, get a ticket# and then poll the service once every couple of minutes with the ticket until I get a result back. 

Since this is all happening without refreshing the page, I would have to create routing calls in the controller, one which only makes the request and the other that polls the web service, which seems very redundant. 

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can load load all data by AJAX. Is Very simply.

First create Controller who return JSON to View.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data= "your data from db or web service"
        return Json(data);
    }
```

Second get data using AJAX.

```
function GetData(cityID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Controler/GetData',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (results) {
          //your data is in results varible
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
}
```

This is very fast becouse all methods will be call async.

Comment: In other words, use the controller to route all the calls? Is that the most efficient way to do it properly?